# Deleting files in Linux with a loop using `rm`

Tags: linux, bash

I have files like `file.log.1.gz`, `file.log.2.gz`, …, `file.log.100.gz`. I want to have a loop from `1` to `100` to delete these files. How can this be done?

I tried this command in Linux:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100); do rm -rf file.log.$i.gz
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that command?

Comment: Should I copy that command, paste into terminal and run .... hmm ... thinks .... no thanks, rm is the command of the devil : make sure you are sure what it will do...

Comment: Why not just remove the folder holding those files and then replace it? Worked a treat to remove 180000 files in several folders in the past....

Comment: Because I need that folder, I have 50+ files there that I need, so I cant just delete it.
The command I use is in bash and it doesn't do anything, although I know that: for i in $(seq 1 100), is a loop in bash

Comment: While your seq solution is will do this, if its for log file maintenance, and you want to get rid of old logs you can run something like 'find /path/to/dir -type f -ctime +XXX -exec rm {} +` where XXX is the number of days you want to keep.  You may want to replace rm with echo the first time round to check it does what you want.   You can add this file to run periodically in cron to automatically do this.

Answer (score 4):

Your `done` is missing.

```
for i in $(seq 1 100); do rm -f "file.log.$i.gz"; done
```

I removed `-r` because recursion is useless when the argument is a regular file.

---

This loop-less syntax should also work in `bash`. It feeds all the names to a single `rm`:

```
rm file.log.{1..100}.gz
```